# Should the server to server authentication include User on which behalf the request is made?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, jwt, identityserver4

I am going to implement security (using Identity Server 4). I have mobile application (front end) and few microservices (back end).

General scenario is that User_John calls **Service_A_API** using *User-JWT* token (obtained with Device flow). In order for **Service_A** to complete request, it has to access some data from **Service_B**. **Service_A** is calling **Service_B** using *Server2Server-JWT* token (obtained with Client credentials flow).

*Server2Server-JWT* is "Full access" token, allowing **Service_A** to do operations on any user on **Service_B** (e.g. it can delete user's order, update user's money balance, etc.)

Concerns that I have:

1. Is it correct to assume that *Server2Server-JWT* can have some long lifetime (e.g. 10-20 minutes) and it can be used for many requests originated from many different users?
2. Assuming **Service_A and B** are hosted in AWS (Dockers), is the *Server2Server-JWT* secure in those service's memory? What if (and how) the *Server2Server-JWT* get stolen?
3. Should **Service_A** request new *Server2Server-JWT* token for every user to call **Service_B** (and e.g. store this UserId in Claims)? Or is it safe to assume that *Server2Server-JWT* is safe in memory, and can be reused for any user request within the lifetime span of the full access *Server2Server-JWT* token?
4. Is Hybrid flow an answer to create a Server-to-server token on behalf of a user? Or is it something else?

My source of info are:

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html
https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/asp-dotnet-core-oauth2-openid-connect-securing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely can answer the last question and only try with the rest.

*Hybrid* is a kind of *interactive flow* where one app has both client and server parts. Interactive means that a user goes through the IdP's portal to get authenticated. 
Mobile apps usually run *Authorization Code* authorization flow with *PKCE* extension which all together behave pretty similar to hybrid where the "client" is a mobile browser and the "server" is the app itself.

No place for an API. But... you can look into the [Extension Grant docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html#refextensiongrants). Allows to implement *Service Credentials on behalf of a user*, exactly what you want, but... probably you don't need that with AWS.

They offer [Network firewalls built into Amazon VPC, and web application firewall capabilities in AWS WAF to create private networks, and control access to your instances and applications](https://aws.amazon.com/security/). Together with "Customer-controlled encryption in transit with TLS across all services" that might be more than enough. The decision is yours.

Comment: The token retrieved using Extension Grant should be cached by API1 for the duration of token lifetime? or it should be single use only?

Comment: It can't be really one time use, as it's a normal jwt, but you are free to set the ttl up to your needs, and it can be reasonably short. You can retrieve a fresh token whenever you need as you constantly keep your client credentials.

Comment: Is keeping that token for let say 20 minutes or 1 hour in API1 memory (e.g. in-memory cache) a standard practice, or is it security flaw?

Comment: I don't think there could be any generic answer. For HR processing that must be ok, but for banking transactions or some reservation could be too much. When you have full control over your API hosting, you are limited by your business logic only. Anyway, and it's a general rule, we should not set the ttl longer than we really need (just in case)